# Azure triggered webjob not triggering when there are message in azure service bus

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

I have a web job that is supposed to be a triggered web job. I have it been deployed to azure fine and it is listed as a triggered webjob. However when I add things to the azure service bus that it has a function for. When i trigger it from the UI it works and will respond to my messages.

My host is configured like so

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration
        {
            JobActivator = new MyActivator(container)
        };
        config.UseServiceBus();
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
```

My Function looks something like this

```
public  void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("recipetest")] ProductName message, TextWriter log)
    {
        //code
    }
```

I have been looking for a while now but all google searches have given me back continuous web jobs with function triggers. Can anyone tell me how to get the web job to wake up and handle messages. I have found most other answers talk about always on but triggered jobs should work without always on.

Comment: Yeah you need a continuous job with "always on"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use ServiceBusTrigger, your WebJob has to be continuous.

To add a little more detail, the ServiceBusTriggerAttribute actually does poll the Message Queue that it monitors using a backoff if no messages are found. So you can see that messages added to the queue do not "wake up" a WebJob and tell it to do something - instead the ServiceBusTriggerAttribute polls and will find when new messages are waiting to be processed. This is why the WebJob can't be Triggered if you're using ServiceBusTriggerAttribute.

Comment: Wait - it doesn't subscribe like normal service bus queue clients? Polling is necessary for storage queue, but if I need to implement anything even remotely responsive, polling is a killer.

Comment: @Volker, that is correct. The ServiceBusTrigger is actually open source and you can see for yourself that it actually does monitor the service bus queue via polling. This can actually handle a ton of traffic though. You can specify how many messages can be dequeued at once. You can also specify the max interval between polls. And since a message is locked when read, you can dial up the number of webjob instances checking a queue if you really need to cook.

Comment: Where do I actually find the source? I got the sdk and the extensions from github, but I don't see anything about the servicebus in there. Regarding traffic, my concern is not throughput but roundtrip time.

Comment: @Volker, the source for the trigger is here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/ServiceBusTriggerAttribute.cs. Note that there's quite a few classes that make up the ServiceBus Trigger. As for roundtrip time, my two cents is to make sure that your webjob is located in the same datacenter as your Service Bus Queue to reduce latency, and set the max polling interval to something small. Doing so will up your financial cost, though.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the differences between continuous webJob and trigger webjob is as below:

Continuous webJob: Always run a backend exe in the web application.

In webjob SDK ServiceBusTrigger scenarios, even though your individual functions are 'triggered', the WebJob as a while runs continuously (i.e. your exe keeps running and does its own internal triggering).

Triggered webjob: Triggered by schedule or manually.

Notice: Webjobs are all run by the web app's process and web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources.

So both Continuous and Triggered (scheduled CRON) webjobs require 'Always on'.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was two things:

1. Call `ConfigureWebJobs` as follows

```
.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
{
    b.AddServiceBus();
})
```

2. Make sure that function that uses `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute is declared as `public` as well as containing class  (needs to be `public class`).